# How to build Qt project for armv7l architecture?

Tags: c++, qt, build, arm

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.
I have a big Qt project and I need to build it for armv7l architecture. How can I do it? What do I need?
At first, I think I need to build Qt for armv7l? Is it possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Very broad question , but it depends what OS you're using.. the OS should be supported by Qt. E.g., I don't know about Qt5, but Qt 4 could run on linux without X server if built with frame buffer support, which made it usable on small embedded  monoblock

Comment: I use CentOS to build. The system where application will start is Ubuntu. The question is how to build it for armv7l architecture. I think it's something like aarch32

Comment: oh, you do it in canadian way? you have to get arm toolchain onto you X86 system

Comment: First, you need a compiler that can produce code for ARMv7I architecture.  Next, you may need to modify the initialization code (that runs before `main()`).  You'll also need to set up Qt for platform options, such as video card and operating system calls.  And you may need to build the Qt library for the ARMv7I processor.